# elasticsearch terms aggregation output keys

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Suppose I have a document like

```
doc :{
   item: {name: "Movie1", code: "M1"}
}
```

I can simply use `terms` aggregation on item.code and get all the buckets. But, is it possible to use aggregation on `item.code` but get the output bucket key to be the value of `item.name`

PS: I know I could use `item.name` in the `terms` aggregation, but due the nature of data (the names store vary slightly hence I have to use code), I need to bucket by `code` but output key as `name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what you are looking for but it does what you need:

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "whatever": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "item.code",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top1": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": {"exclude": "*"},
            "fields": ["item.name"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```